# Numeric function

Tags: function, math

As a sub-routine for a script I'm writing, I need a numerical function that behaves in a specific pattern. It takes a single input and provides a single output, such that between 0 and L inclusive, it is the identity function, but then between L+1 and L*2+1, it returns L to 0 respectively, and then from L*2+2 to L*3+2 it returns 0 to L respectively, and so on. I want to do this without any if statements, only using absolute value and modulus. Can anyone give me pseudocode for this function?

Comment: it seems your function will have consecutive zeroes and Ls.

Comment: Yes, that is intentional. I also am assuming that integer math is not a valid hack, as the language of preference is JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given input `I`, limit `L` and result `R`, and using only basic arithmetic and absolute values, this gives the desired result.

```
R = ABS(L * ((I - (I % (L + 1))) / (L + 1) % 2) + (L + 1) * (I - (I % (L + 1))) / (L + 1) - I)
```

---

This can obviously be hugely simplified by declaring some intermediate variables, and using additional methods, e.g. `floor` to simulate integer division. Here's a Javascript example:

```
var factor = Math.floor(input / (limit + 1));
var flag = factor % 2;
var result = Math.abs(limit * flag + (limit + 1) * factor - input)
```

Comment: No, that does not appear to be correct.
Example output assuming L = 3:
0 -> 0,
1 -> 0,
2 -> 0,
3 -> 3,
4 -> 3,
5 -> 3,
6 -> 0
...

Comment: Yes, I'm telling you what your output is. That is not what I want. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Should be correct, I've added another couple of brackets. What are you evaluating this in?

Comment: JavaScript console. Precise enough for this purpose.

Comment: You're assuming integer math. This is floating-point math. 2/3 = .66666667, not 0

Comment: I'm indeed assuming integer math. If you're using floating point, add a `FLOOR()`.

Comment: The last one is incorrect. For I=L+1 to L*2+1, it yields L-1 to 0 and then 1 for L*2+1. It does not meet the rules of my question.